# Export Jupyter notebook to HTML with line numbers?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

If I turn on line numbers in my code cells in a Jupyter Notebook the rendered output when I go to download as HTML does not include the line numbers in the output.

Is there a setting in nbconvert that allows this? (I did not see anything obvious in the nbconvert docs)

If not, is it possible with custom templating in nbconvert?

Why: I want to be able to reference Line numbers from my markdown cells for tutorials.

Ipython 6.1.0
nbconvert 5.3.1
jupyter client 5.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was solved [in this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5847) of the ipyhton GitHub repository.

Basically **nbconvert hasn't got** a setting for this, but you can create a **custom template** to get the result you need.